# How to bind string value from livewire frontend to property into integer casted?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component, which binds an attribute named `department_id` directly inside the property model.
The problem is, neither I define the model attribute cast `department_id` => `integer` or not defined, my Livewire component stores it as a `string`, not the `integer` when it received it from the frontend.

Below is the screenshot of the whole livewire component dumped by `phpdebugbar`.

[image: capture from phpdebugbar]

So my question is, ***How can I bind the `string` data from frontend directly inside model property, casted as `integer`?***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class Form extends Component
{
    public User $user;

    protected $rules = [
        'user.department_id' => ['nullable', 'integer'],
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.form');
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->user->save();
    }
}
```

```
<!-- /resources/views/livewire/form.blade.php -->
<select name="department-id" id="department-id" wire:model.lazy="user.department_id">
    <option value="1" {{ $user->department_id == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Department #1</option>
    <option value="2" {{ $user->department_id == 2 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Department #2</option>
    <option value="3" {{ $user->department_id == 3 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Department #3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you get any error because it is stored as string? I think Livewire takes care that the correct types are properly passed to the model and to Eloquent.

Comment: In some cases, the select component doesn't show up as $user->department_id is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Values from inputs are always strings. Even values from `<input type="number">` but you don't have to worry about it, as Laravel and the database handles it for you.

If you pass the string `"3"` when saving the model id, it will be stored correctly as an integer, given that the column type in the database is an integer.

Answer (score -1):

You can cast the property on the model, by setting the `$casts` property on your User model. Originally all data retrieved from a database is a string, you have to specifically cast it.

```
protected $casts = [
    'department_id' => 'integer',
];
```

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting